# JSON.parse can't recognize \" (backslash and quote) in string to parse

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I have serialized JSON with objects that have quotes in string like this:

```
var bla = [
    { 
        "label": "person", 
        "id": "1", 
        "data": "bla means: \"lala\"" 
    }
];
```

I know how it looks on server side. But when I debug it in browser I see that I receive error on this because it looks like below:

```
var bla = [
    { 
        "label": "person", 
        "id": "1", 
        "data": "bla means: "lala"" 
    }
];
```

and my error :

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token l in JSON at position 25 at
>   JSON.parse ()

I read that JSON should recognize **\"** https://www.json.org/

Any ideas where should I correct it? On server side when I serialized object or on client side with JavaScript?

**EDIT:**

On server side I use C# library `"System.Web.Script.Serialization"`
The object to serialize:

```
List<SomeObject> someObject= new List<SomeObject>();
        SomeObject bla1 = new SomeObject();
        bla1.id = "1";
        bla1.label = "person";
        bla1.label = "bla means: \"lala\"";
        someObject.Add(bla1);
```

`var bla = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(someObject);`

**SUMMARY**

I fix in on serialized string on server side, because I use API where I can't manipulate this objects.
`var bla = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(someObject).Replace("\\\"", "\\\\\\\"");`

Comment: This is probably a server side problem. You should be using a standard JSON library, not trying to serialize by yourself.

Comment: but like i read on json.org it should recognize that \" signs and shoudn't have problem. But in the other way there is no chance to use quotes in string?

Comment: When you use `console.log()` on a string with embedded quotes, it doesn't show the backslash that's needed to enter it as a literal or JSON.

Comment: Post your code that's creating the JSON.

Comment: The documentation recommends using Json.NET rather than JavaScriptSerializer

Comment: I try it also with Json.NET and have the same result

Comment: Are you calling `JSON.parse(response)` or `JSON.parse(bla[0].data)`?

Comment: `JSON.parse(bla)`

Comment: That makes no sense. `bla` is already an object, you don't need to parse it.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, I just use [String.raw()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/raw).

```js
JSON.parse(`{ "key": "\""}`) // fail
JSON.parse(String.raw`{ "key": "\""}`) // work
```

Comment: Use with caution!, it cannot contains ` inside too.
Recommend to serialize JSON instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this with double backslash or triple backslash like `\\" or \\\"`

```
var bla = [
    { 
        "label": "person", 
        "id": "1", 
        "data": "bla means: \\"lala\\"" 
    }
];
```

It will add backslash and print it with double quotes.

Comment: Yes your solution works. But its hard to program becasue I use API from I get those strings.

Comment: Which means you cannot add double backslash?

Comment: Which API are you using?

Comment: Exacly. I need to add it to serialized string or just cut of that \" but i dont want to. Or meaby it's the only way? API example: https://api-v3.mojepanstwo.pl/dane/krs_podmioty/23302.json?layers=graph

Comment: Yes, this is the only way, because '\' is used as a part of escape sequence that is why your server is not recognizing the double quotes in the string. It is treating \" as an escape sequence.

Answer (score 1):

The server should serve proper serialized JSON that can be parsed directly, without the client having to do tricky string manipulations on the data first. (For example, if you don't fix it server-side, then it becomes invalid to `fetch(...).then(res => res.json())`)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fully understand your project's structure, but:

**backslash** `\` is a special character in javascript.

It is special because it has a regex special meaning.

1. When writing `\hello`, your output would be `hello`
2. When writing `\'hello`, your output would be `'hello`.
3. When writing `\"hello\"`, your output would be `"hello"`

I think you should first choose how exactly you want your `data` property to be formatted.

Do you want data to be a string? array? object? a string which keeps all of its quotation marks as double or single?

Have a look here - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp

And decide the string format you want to work with.

If you want to *escape a character* (which actually means to have it in your string), you should add `\` before this character.